# Angular - class objects and reactive forms

Tags: angular, reactive

I know this is probably out there somewhere already on stackoverflow, but the posts are a bit convoluted, and I'd like to start fresh here.

How do I connect data from a json file - to 2 things at once:

1. A class consisting of objects & data that mimic the data file.
2. The controls on each component (consisting of pieces of the data).

Example:

One giant reactive form.

```
  component1 - contains incident header data
  component2 - contains incident analysis data
  component3 - contains incident decision data
  etc...
```

One .json file:

```
  {
  "incidents": [
  {
   "id": 1, 
   "headerData":{...}, 
   "analysisData":{...}, 
   "decisionData": {...}, 
    etc...
  }
  {
   "id": 2, 
   "headerData":{...}, 
   "analysisData":{...}, 
   "decisionData": {...}, 
    etc...
  },
  {etc...}
 ]
}
```

each {...} containing deeper objects.

And finally I have my Incident class, which basically mimics the .json file data:

```
export class Incident
    id: string,
    headerData: HeaderData,
    analysisData:  AnalysisData,
    decisionData: DecisionData,
    etc...

export class HeaderData
    etc...
```

What is the best way to populate these objects of the class as well as the reactive form controls (that also mimic the data).
In other words:

Should I have one class object (Incident) that's global and contains the data
   and then distributed to the reactive form components.

Or should I have each component pull in their respective sections from the 
   file (or from the class??)

Finally, is the class using a service to grab the data, or should the separate 
   components each grab their parts using a service - or does a global store 
   negate the need for a service?

Sorry, for all the questions - just trying to piece it all together!